# Command to reboot into Linux from Mac?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bootloader, refind

I have a Mac Mini that I use rEFInd to dual boot with ubuntu.  Is there a terminal command I can use to reboot between them without having to have physical access to the computer to access the mac bootloader?

Comment: you can change the `default_selection` before you reboot it.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/348463/refind-configuration-change-boot-order-and-default-boot

Comment: probably `sudo systemsetup -setstartupdisk /Volumes/disk`